# Switch multiple div position jquery every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help to switch many div (#box) positions every 3 seconds using Javascript or Jquery. Thank you in advance.

Here the HTML code:

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box">
     <div class="molecule img">
     </div>
     <p>molecule 1 description</p>
   </div>
  <div class="box">
     <div class="molecule img">
     </div>
     <p>molecule 2 description</p>
   </div>
  <div class="box">
     <div class="molecule img">
     </div>
     <p>molecule 3 description</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)**, following is an example which switches to div and change it's text color.

```js
var $div = $('.box'),
  index = 0,
  length = $div.length;
setInterval(function() {
  $div.css('color', 'black').eq(index).css('color', 'red');
  index = ++index % length;
}, 3000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="molecule img">
    </div>
    <p>molecule 1 description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="molecule img">
    </div>
    <p>molecule 2 description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="molecule img">
    </div>
    <p>molecule 3 description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE :**  moving first div to the end of container

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('.box:first').appendTo($('.box').parent());
}, 3000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="molecule img">
    </div>
    <p>molecule 1 description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="molecule img">
    </div>
    <p>molecule 2 description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="molecule img">
    </div>
    <p>molecule 3 description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But It's not exactly what i need, i wanted the first div to take the place of the second one and the second of first, and randomly they keep switching their positions each 3 seconds.

Comment: @MsQueen : glad to help :)